# Can't connect to virtual Cent OS server from Windows 7 Virtual Machine

Tags: windows, centos, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I'm completely stumped. I'm running Ubuntu 11.04 as the host. I also have a virtual Cent OS server running in VirtualBox. With a browser on my host (Ubuntu), I can hit the server and see my web pages so all is fine and dandy. Unfortunately though, I also have to test with Internet Explorer ugh...

So I set up a Windows guest running in VirtualBox as well. So my setup now is 1 host (Ubuntu) with 2 guests (Cent OS and Windows). Now I can ping my server from the Windows VM and also browse the Internet but I can't access my web pages! I'm using IE8 and I keep getting: Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage. Stupid Windows...

Any ideas?

Comment: what kinds of networks do you have configured? NAT, Bridge, Host-Only, internal network? Did you check the network configurations and firewalls? Is there probably a proxy server used in the windows system?

Comment: The Cent OS server and Windows are both configured with a Bridged connection. The server is listening to all incoming IP's from port 80 and iptables is configured to allow traffic through port 80.

Comment: Did you try to access the page with a different browser on your Windows machine?

Comment: Yeah Google Chrome can't find the website either..

Comment: Maybe some subnet issue? What's the net mask set to?

Comment: Subnet Mask is 255.255.254.0

Comment: Okay, I think I know what the problem is. When I do tracert on the virtual server's IP address on Windows, I don't even reach the server. There's only one hop and it's the company's dhcp server! Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh, I can't believe I spent two days on this issue. It turns out I needed to add the IP address of the virtual server to the Windows hosts file.

I thought the hosts file was only used to translate domain names to their respective IP addresses. Before, I had been entering the IP address of my virtual CentOS server directly into the address bar so I didn't think the hosts file required any modifications. But alas...now that I've updated it, it's working.